# Bootstrap 4: зачем нужен метод $('.alert').alert()

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Приведённый пример (скопирован 1 в 1 из документации) состоит из одного лишь только HTML-кода. Alert прекрасно закрывается без единой строчки *самостоятельно написанного* JS-кода ([пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/172229/)).

```html
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Но тогда возникает вопрос: зачем же нужен метод `$('.alert').alert()`? В документации сказано:

> Not necessary when using the data-api’s auto-initialization.

но я не понял, что это за `data-api’s auto-initialization`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Бутстрап предусмотрел два способа использовать свои JS плагины:

1. Написать скрипт с помощью методов и событий из документации Бутстрапа.
2. Расставить атрибуты `data`, как указано в документации.

Во втором случае Бутстрап запустит всё сам, а данные, необходимые для инициализации и работы, возьмёт из `data` атрибутов. Именно это и подразумевает фраза, которую вы процитировали.

Вы можете выбрать, какой способ вам больше подходит, или объединить их: базовое поведение инициализировать через `data` атрибуты, а остальное запрограммировать скриптом.

Авто-инициализация не сработает, если HTML-блок добавляется скриптом после загрузки страницы. Тогда придётся запускать вручную, через `$('.alert').alert()`, например.

И, если нужно, [авто-инициализацию можно отключить](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/javascript/#data-attributes) полностью

```
$(document).off('.data-api')
```

или для какого-нибудь конкретного плагина

```
$(document).off('.alert.data-api')
```

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ! Благодарю Вас за объяснение.